# How do you perform conditional operations on different elements in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a Pandas Dataframe of the price and stock history of a product at 10 different points in time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[np.arange(10)])
df['price'] = 10,10,11,15,20,10,10,11,15,20
df['stock'] = 30,20,13,8,4,30,20,13,8,4
df
```

```
  price stock
0   10  30
1   10  20
2   11  13
3   15  8
4   20  4
5   10  30
6   10  20
7   11  13
8   15  8
9   20  4
```

How do I perform operations between specific rows that meet certain criteria?

In my example row 0 and row 5 meet the criteria "stock over 25" and row 4 and row 9 meet the criteria "stock under 5".

I would like to calculate:

```
df['price'][4] - df['price'][0] and
df['price'][9] - df['price'][5]

but not
df['price'][9] - df['price'][0] or
df['price'][4] - df['price'][5].
```

In other words, I would like to calculate the price change between the most recent event where stock was under 5 vs the most recent event where stock was over 25; over the whole series.

Of course, I would like to do this over larger datasets where picking them manually is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set up data frame and add some calculations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[np.arange(10)])
df['price'] = 10,10,11,15,20,10,10,11,15,20
df['stock'] = 30,20,13,8,4,30,20,13,8,4
df['stock_under_5'] = df['stock'] < 5
df['stock_over_25'] = df['stock'] > 25
df['cum_stock_under_5'] = df['stock_under_5'].cumsum()
df['change_stock_under_5'] = df['cum_stock_under_5'].diff()
df['change_stock_under_5'].iloc[0] = df['stock_under_5'].iloc[0]*1
df['next_row_change_stock_under_5'] = df['change_stock_under_5'].shift(-1)
df['cum_stock_over_25'] = df['stock_over_25'].cumsum()
df['change_stock_over_25'] = df['cum_stock_over_25'].diff()
df['change_stock_over_25'].iloc[0] = df['stock_over_25'].iloc[0]*1
df['next_row_change_stock_over_25'] = df['change_stock_over_25'].shift(-1)
df['row'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])
df['next_row'] = df['row'].shift(-1)
df['next_row_price'] = df['price'].shift(-1)
```

Next we find all windows where either the stock went over 25 or below 5 by grouping over the cumulative marker of those events.

```
changes = (
    df.groupby(['cum_stock_under_5', 'cum_stock_over_25'])
    .agg({'row':'first', 'next_row':'last', 'change_stock_under_5':'max', 'change_stock_over_25':'max', 
          'next_row_change_stock_under_5':'max', 'next_row_change_stock_over_25':'max', 
          'price':'first', 'next_row_price':'last'})
    .assign(price_change = lambda x: x['next_row_price'] - x['price'])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

For each window we find what happened at the beginning of the window: if `change_stock_under_5 = 1` it means the window started with the stock going under 5, if `change_stock_over_25 = 1` it started with the stock going over 25.

Same for the end of the window using the columns `next_row_change_stock_under_5` and `next_row_change_stock_over_25`

Now, we can readily extract the stock price change in rows where the stock went from being over 25 to being under 5:

```
from_over_to_below = changes[(changes['change_stock_over_25']==1) & (changes['next_row_change_stock_under_5']==1)]
```

and the other way around:

```
from_below_to_over = changes[(changes['change_stock_under_5']==1) & (changes['next_row_change_stock_over_25']==1)]
```

You can for example calculate the average price change when the stock went from over 25 to below 5:

```
from_over_to_below.price_change.mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to give a better explanation, will separate the approach by creating two different functions:

1. The first one will be the event detection, let's call it `detect_event`.
2. The second one will calculate the the price between the current event and the previous one, in the list generated by the first function. We will call it `calculate_price_change`.

---

Starting with the first function, here it is key to understand very well the goals we want to reach or the constraints/conditions we want to satisfy.

Will leave two, of more, potential options, given the various interpretations of the question:

A. The initial is what I could get from my initial understanding

B. The second part will be one of the interpretations one could get from [@Iyar Lyn comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73553299/how-do-you-perform-conditional-operations-on-different-elements-in-a-pandas-data/73553408?noredirect=1#comment129891081_73553408) (I can see more interpretations, but won't consider in this answer as the approach will be similar).

Within option A, we will create a function to detect where a stock is under 5 or 25

```
def detect_event(df):
    # Create a list of the indexes of the events where stock was under 5 or over 25
    events = []
    # Loop through the dataframe
    for i in range(len(df)):
        # If stock is under 5, add the index to the list
        if df['stock'][i] < 5:
            events.append(i)
        # If stock is over 25, add the index to the list
        elif df['stock'][i] > 25:
            events.append(i)
    # Return the list of indexes of the events where stock was under 5 or over 25
    return events
```

The comments make it self-explanatory, but, basically, this will return a list of indexes of the rows where stock is under 5 or over 25.

With OP's df this will return

```
events = detect_event(df)

[Out]:
[0, 4, 5, 9]
```

Within the option B, assuming one wants to know the events where the stock went from under 5 to over 25, and vice-versa, **consecutively** (there are more ways to interpret this), then one can use the following function

```
def detect_event(df):
    # Create a list of the indexes of the events where we will store the elements in the conditions
    events = []

    for i, stock in enumerate(df['stock']):
        # If the index is 0, add the index of the first event to the list of events
        if i == 0:
            events.append(i)
        # If the index is not 0, check if the stock went from over 25 to under 5 or from under 5 to over 25
        else:
            # If the stock went from over 25 to under 5, add the index of the event to the list of events
            if stock < 5 and df['stock'][i-1] > 25:
                events.append(i)
            # If the stock went from under 5 to over 25, add the index of the event to the list of events
            elif stock > 25 and df['stock'][i-1] < 5:
                events.append(i)

    # Return the list of events
    return events
```

With OP's df this will return

```
events = detect_event(df)

[Out]:
[0, 5]
```

Note that `0` is the element in the first position, that we are appending by default.

---

As for the second function, once the conditions are well defined, meaning we know clearly what we want, and adapted the first function, `detect_event`, accordingly, we can now detect the changes in the prices.

In order to detect the price change between the events that satisfy the conditions we defined previously, one will use a different function: `calculate_price_change`.

This function will take both the dataframe `df` and the list `events` generated by the previous function, and return a list with the prices diferences.

```
def calculate_price_change(df, events):
    # Create a list to store the price change between the most recent event where stock was under 5 vs the most recent event where stock was over 25
    price_change = []
    # Loop through the list of indexes of the events
    for i, event in enumerate(events):
        # If the index is 0, the price change is 0
        if i == 0:
            price_change.append(0)
        # If the index is not 0, calculate the price change between the current and past events
        else:
            price_change.append(df['price'][event] - df['price'][events[i-1]])
    return price_change
```

Now we if one calls this last function using the `df` and the list created with the first function `detect_event`, one gets the following

```
price_change = calculate_price_change(df, events)

[Out]:
[0, 10, -10, 10]
```

---